# BodyKt$main$Person@35cabb2a what is it? And can I get properties of it?

Tags: class, kotlin, copy, deep-copy

I create object of class and try to copy it.

I tried to get properties of object but got this out:

```
Properties of Ann: Name: Ann Age: 10 Type: man High: 0.5 Code: 1408
Properties of Bob: Name: Bob Age: 20 Type: girl High: 15.0 Code: 1239
Default: Name: Orig Age: 18 Type: piece High: 25.7 Code: 1522
Bob has Anns' props: Name: Ann Age: 10 Type: man High: 0.5 Code: 1408
Default list: [BodyKt$main$Person@35cabb2a]
```

Code:

```
fun main() {
    // copy object in object
    class Person (var name: String = "Orig", var type: String = "piece",
                       var age: Int = 18, var high: Double = 25.7, var code: Int = 1522)
    {
        var info: String = "0"
            get() = "Name: $name Age: $age Type: $type High: $high Code: $code"
        val somebody
            get () = listOf(Person("Copy", "some", 15, 11.1, 1870))
    }
    var default: Person = Person()
    val ann: Person = Person("Ann", "man", 10, 0.5, 1408) // 1st object with some properties
    var bob: Person = Person("Bob", "girl", 20, 15.0, 1239) // 2nd object without prop
    println("Properties of Ann: ${ann.info}") // props 1st object
    println("Properties of Bob: ${bob.info}") // props 2nd object
    println("Default: ${default.info}") // props default
    bob = ann.deepCopy() // copy 1st in 2nd
    println("Bob has Anns' props: ${bob.info}") // new props 2nd object
    println("Default list: ${default.somebody}")
}
```

Default list: `[BodyKt$main$Person@35cabb2a]` what is it?

Answer (score 1):

It's the result of [the default `toString` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), because you don't override it for `Person`: `BodyKt$main$Person` is the JVM class name because it's defined inside `main`.

It looks like your `info` should just be replaced by an override of `toString`:

```
fun main() {
    // copy object in object
    class Person (var name: String = "Orig", var type: String = "piece",
                       var age: Int = 18, var high: Double = 25.7, var code: Int = 1522)
    {
        override fun toString() = "Name: $name Age: $age Type: $type High: $high Code: $code"
        val somebody
            get () = listOf(Person("Copy", "some", 15, 11.1, 1870))
    }
    var default: Person = Person()
    val ann: Person = Person("Ann", "man", 10, 0.5, 1408) // 1st object with some properties
    var bob: Person = Person("Bob", "girl", 20, 15.0, 1239) // 2nd object without prop
    println("Properties of Ann: $ann") // props 1st object
    println("Properties of Bob: $bob") // props 2nd object
    println("Default: $default") // props default
    bob = ann.deepCopy() // copy 1st in 2nd
    println("Bob has Anns' props: $bob") // new props 2nd object
    println("Default list: ${default.somebody}")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you give me some recommendation about resources what I can use to learn more about Kotlin with some examples?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html? Without being more specific about what you don't understand, it's hard to answer.